# glm.nb with sqrt link

Tags: r, statistics

i'm trying to fit a negbin model with sqrt link. Unfortunately it seems to be that I have to specify starting values. Is anybody familiar with setting starting values when running the `glm.nb` command (package `MASS`)?

When I don't use starting values, I get an error message:

> no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

Looking at `?glm.nb` it seems to be possible to set starting values, unfortunately I absolutely don't know how to do this. Some further information: 1.When computing the regression with the standard log link, the regression can be estimated. 2. It is not possible to set the start value for the algorithm to an arbitrary value, so for example

```
glm.nb(<model>,link=sqrt, start=1)
```

does not work!

Comment: A reproducible example would be highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finding suitable starting values can be difficult for sufficiently complex problems. However for setting the starting values (the documentation of which is not great, but exists) you should learn to read the error messages. Here is a replicate of your unsuccessful attempt using `start=1` with a built-in data set:

```
>quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex + Age + Eth + Lrn, data = quine, 
                    link=sqrt, start=1)
Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, start = start, etastart = etastart,  : 
  length of 'start' should equal 7 and correspond to initial coefs for 
  c("(Intercept)", "SexM", "AgeF1", "AgeF2", "AgeF3", "EthN", "LrnSL", )
```

It tells you exactly what it is expecting: a vector of values for each coefficient to be estimated.

```
quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex + Age + Eth + Lrn, data = quine, 
                    link=sqrt, start=rep(1,7))
```

works, because I gave a vector of length 7. You might have to play around with the actual values in it to get a model that always predicts positive values. It is likely that the default algorithm of generating starting values in `glm.nb` gives negative prediction somewhere, and the `sqrt` link cannot tolerate that (unlike the `log`). If you are having trouble finding valid starting values by hand, you can try running a simpler model, and expand estimates from it by 0's for the other parameters to get a good starting location.

**EDIT: building up a model**

Suppose you can't find valid starting values for your complicated model. Then start with a simple one, for example

```
> nb0 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex, data=quine, link=sqrt)
> coef(nb0)
(Intercept)        SexM 
  3.9019226   0.3353578
```

Now let's add the next variable using the previous starting values by adding 0 estimates for the effect of the new variable (in this case `Age` has four levels, so needs 3 coefficients):

```
> nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex+Age, data=quine, link=sqrt, start=c(coef(nb0), 0,0,0))
> coef(nb1)
(Intercept)        SexM       AgeF1       AgeF2       AgeF3 
  3.9127405  -0.1155013  -0.5551010   0.7475166   0.5933048
```

You usually want to keep adding 0's and not, say, 100's, because a coefficient of 0 means that the new variable has no effect - which is exactly what the simpler model that you just fitted assumes.

Comment: Thanks Aniko! Little closer, but not close enough :) As you said i added the starting values and changed the values from start=rep(1,7) to (for example) start=rep(100,7). But this does not work. I don't really understand the algorithm behind the glm.nb command. What is the reason that it does not converge? And what exactly do you mean with expanding the estimates from it by 0's? Thanks so far!

Comment: With the `quine` data starting with `rep(100,7)` does converge, even though it is way out from the correct estimates. It is hard to theorize what's going wrong with your data without having any clue about how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error while doing the RR regression using log link binomial as shown below

```
adjrep <-glm(reptest ~ momagecat + paritycat + marstatcat + dept,
             family = binomial(link = "log"),
             data = hcm1)

> Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply
> starting values
```

After following up on the instructions of building up a model I arrived on the code below and got coefficients for each the variables below.

```
rep3 <-glm (reptest ~ momagecat + paritycat + marstatcat + dept,
            family = binomial(link = "log"),
            data = hcm1,
            start=c(coef(rep1),0,0,0))
```

Comment: How does that link to the question?